# ubuntu 13.04, wifi not detecting after restarting PC, after a weekly software updates installation

Tags: 13.04, wireless, networking, drivers, updates

I am pretty new to Ubuntu and been using it along with windows 7 since past few weeks. I manage to resolve all those preliminary issues with WiFi adapter(Drivers and all) after a fresh Ubuntu installation. But today it asked for a software updates(not 13.10, just a regular update i believe). I updated and restarted my PC. Since then its not showing any WiFi connections at all. I checked in the additional drivers section in the software updates tab but its all empty. I have a D-Link USB WiFi adapter. The following command gives no output in the shell.

```
sudo lshw -C network
```

I remember it used to give some details about my network earlier, but its not showing anything at all.
One more thing, the Fifi USB adapter is working fine in windows 7 and also when booting it from Ubuntu Live USB.

```
lsusb 

output: 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8008 Intel Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 046d:c31d Logitech, Inc. 
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 046d:c05a Logitech, Inc. Optical Mouse M90
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 2001:3309 D-Link Corp. DWA-135 802.11n Wireless N Adapter(rev.A1) [Realtek RTL8192CU]
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
```

Comment: Please edit your question to add the result of this terminal command: lsusb

Comment: did that. please have a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your wireless device is supposed to work with the driver rtl8192cu. Let's load it and see if your wireless starts:

```
sudo modprobe rtl8192cu
```

If so, let's get it to load automatically:

```
sudo -i
echo rtl8192cu >> /etc/modules
exit
```

If loading the module doesn't help, let's look for clues in the logs:

```
rfkill list all
dmesg | grep -i rtl
```

Comment: Hey Thanks for the answer, loading the module helped, its detecting the wifi now. But now i am back to the same problem that i was having earlier after the installation of ubuntu 13.04. Wifi frequently disconnects. It shows as connected but pages won't load. I have to disconnect and try connecting it again. I don't exactly remember how i had fixed it then.

Comment: But i remember trying a lot of commands and options through various online comments and answers to the issues similar to this. I am gonna try and repeat my research on the same again. Meanwhile if its possible for you to post an answer/reply to this new issue then i would be grateful. Thanks again.

Comment: updated wifi drivers and it resolved the frequent dropping of net.